# CSS drop down menu for touch screen. Using active as hover

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, drop-down-menu

What I'm trying to do is create a drop down menu to use on a mobile website. Since you can't hover over a menu item to see the submenu, i need to get around that problem.  I've researched this and attempted to solve this problem. A lot of sites recommend using JS with the onclick function. I cant get a grip of it. Thanks.

Here is the HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="phone.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="smenu_div">    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
        </li>   
            </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Here is CSS.

```
/*Small Menu*/
.smenu_div ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:35px; 
    margin-right:40px;
    font-family:georgia;
    font-size:60px;
    color:#ffffff;
    list-style:none;
    text-indent:15px;
    text-align:center; 
    width:35%;
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.smenu_div ul li
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background:#000000;
    line-height:justified;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.smenu_div li ul:active{ display: block; }

.smenu_div ul li a
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
}
.smenu_div ul li a:hover
{
    color:#000000;
    background:#fdff30;
}
.smenu_div ul li#active
{
    color:#000000;
    background:#fdff30;
}
```

Comment: I do notice that it seems last </li> is in the wrong place, in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I can barely get your question, but for creating menus to use in websites for small screen with html and css, try http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/

Comment: I looked at that page already. It doesn't work in my mobile browser. Also im not interested in any detection for converting. It is purely for a mobile site.

Answer (score 0):

just adjust the CSS within the onclick function.

HTML:

```
<div id="menuclick">Click to show menu</div>

<div id="hiddenMenu" style="display: none;">
    TEXT GOES HERE
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var hidden = true;
document.getElementById('menuclick').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('hiddenMenu').style.display = (hidden) ? 'block' : 'none';
    hidden = !hidden;
};
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/F5nJT/1/

if you want a floating menu you'll want to play with the css position of the element so that it doesn't cause the document to reflow when its display changes.